# Get the xpath of tag inside the CDATA in xml

Tags: xml, xpath, jmeter, cdata

I wanted to get the xpath of the **report** tag having attribute **displayName="Support Report"** under the CDATA  in the given xml.
I need a xquery to use in the jmeter Xpath extractor.please help.Thanks in advance!!!!!!

FULL XML:--

```
<ReportExecuted>
<ExecutedBy>admin</ExecutedBy>
<ExecutionTime>Mon Apr 10 10:06:25 UTC 2017</ExecutionTime>
<ReportContent>
    <![CDATA[
        <reports>
            <reportGroup name="License Reports">
            </reportGroup>
            <reportGroup name="Customer Reports">
            </reportGroup>
            <reportGroup name="Entitlement Reports">
            </reportGroup>
            <reportGroup name="Audit Log Reports">
                <report id="7" displayName="Audit Log Report">
                    <inputParameter name="StartDate" displayName="Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EndDate" displayName="End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
            </reportGroup>
            <reportGroup name="Custom Reports">
                <report id="1327" displayName="supportRpt_Testing">
                    <inputParameter name="BackOffice" displayName="BackOffice" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="54" displayName="Splitter">
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="ContactEmail" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="191" displayName="Custom Activation Report">
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="PageSize" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="START_DATE" displayName="START_DATE" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="END_DATE" displayName="END_DATE" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ORDER_NUMBER" displayName="ORDER_NUMBER" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PRODUCT_NUMBER" displayName="PRODUCT_NUMBER" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="FAMILY" displayName="FAMILY" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="SAID" displayName="SAID" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EMAIL" displayName="EMAIL" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="HPSN" displayName="HPSN" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="COMPANY" displayName="COMPANY" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ORDER_TYPE" displayName="ORDER_TYPE" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="LOCKING_ID" displayName="LOCKING_ID" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="PageNo" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="2761" displayName="aruba test">
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="186" displayName="Custom Entitlement Report">
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="PageSize" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="START_DATE" displayName="START_DATE" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="END_DATE" displayName="END_DATE" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ORDER_NUMBER" displayName="ORDER_NUMBER" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PRODUCT_NUMBER" displayName="PRODUCT_NUMBER" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="FAMILY" displayName="FAMILY" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="SAID" displayName="SAID" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EMAIL" displayName="EMAIL" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="COMPANY" displayName="COMPANY" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ORDER_TYPE" displayName="ORDER_TYPE" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="PageNo" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="52" displayName="test support report">
                    <inputParameter name="BackOffice" displayName="BackOffice" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="StartDate" displayName="StartDate" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="NumberofDays" displayName="NumberofDays" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="2650" displayName="testEnt">
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="PageSize" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="PageNo" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="2706" displayName="GetSplitEON">
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
            </reportGroup>
            <reportGroup name="CWP Reports">
                <report id="1275" displayName="CWP service for Regen Rehost using lockings">
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="Locking_ID" displayName="Locking ID" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="Locking_ID1" displayName="Locking ID1" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="Locking_ID2" displayName="Locking ID2" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="NoOfLockings" displayName="No Of Lockings" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="1273" displayName="CWP service for Locking code using Contact Email">
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="1279" displayName="CWP Service for FA EON using lockings">
                    <inputParameter name="Locking_ID" displayName="Locking ID" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="Locking_ID1" displayName="Locking ID1" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="Locking_ID2" displayName="Locking ID2" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="NoOfLockings" displayName="No Of Lockings" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="1278" displayName="CWP service for Download Keys using Key Ids">
                    <inputParameter name="LicenseKeyIDs" displayName="License Key IDs" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="1277" displayName="CWP service for EONS Product Details using EON">
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="1272" displayName="CWP Service for Activations using Contact Email">
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="1270" displayName="Entitlement List Report">
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EONs" displayName="EONs" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductFamily" displayName="Product Family" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EntitlementStatus" displayName="Entitlement Status" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNos" displayName="Order Nos" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="87" displayName="CWP Service for Multi EON Search">
                    <inputParameter name="EONs" displayName="EONs" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3316" displayName="CWP Service for Activation Asset View">
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="FamilyId" displayName="Family Id" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3315" displayName="CWP Service for Product Family by Contact Email">
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3314" displayName="CWP Associated EONs By ContactEmail">
                    <inputParameter name="EmailId" displayName="Email Id" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="StartDate" displayName="Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EndDate" displayName="End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="FilterOutAvailableAssets" displayName="Filter Out Available Assets" type="BOOLEAN"/>
                </report>
                <report id="1286" displayName="CWP Report for Activation Lockings using EONs">
                    <inputParameter name="EONs" displayName="EONs" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3318" displayName="CWP Service for Activation Asset Search Count">
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductDescription" displayName="Product Description" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivationStartDate" displayName="Activation Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivationEndDate" displayName="Activation End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="HPESerialNumber" displayName="HPE Serial Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="LockingId" displayName="Locking Id" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="1287" displayName="CWP Report for Product Family List">
                </report>
                <report id="3317" displayName="CWP Service for Activation Asset Search">
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductDescription" displayName="Product Description" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivationStartDate" displayName="Activation Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivationEndDate" displayName="Activation End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="HPESerialNumber" displayName="HPE Serial Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="LockingId" displayName="Locking Id" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
            </reportGroup>
            <reportGroup name="Admin Reports">
                <report id="1289" displayName="Entitlement List Admin Report">
                    <inputParameter name="Company" displayName="Company" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EONs" displayName="EONs" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductFamily" displayName="Product Family" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EntitlementStatus" displayName="Entitlement Status" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNos" displayName="Order Nos" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3311" displayName="Support Report">
                    <inputParameter name="StartDate" displayName="Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="Region" displayName="Region" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="BackOffice" displayName="Back Office" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="IsVMwareProducts" displayName="Is VWware Products" type="BOOLEAN"/>
                    <inputParameter name="NumberofDays" displayName="Number of Days(1-31)" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="1280" displayName="List of Product Description for Specified User">
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="1285" displayName="Locking Code Admin Report">
                    <inputParameter name="Company" displayName="Company" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="LockingCode" displayName="Locking Code" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="1288" displayName="Activation Report">
                    <inputParameter name="Company" displayName="Company" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ContactEmail" displayName="Contact Email" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EONs" displayName="EONs" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductFamily" displayName="Product Family" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EntitlementStatus" displayName="Entitlement Status" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNos" displayName="Order Nos" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
            </reportGroup>
            <reportGroup name="EG-PSP Reports">
                <report id="3307" displayName="Reseller Partner Activation Details Report">
                    <inputParameter name="ActivationId" displayName="Activation Id" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3308" displayName="Partner Order Details Report">
                    <inputParameter name="PartnerId" displayName="Partner Id" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNumber" displayName="Order Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3305" displayName="Reseller Partner Activation Asset Report">
                    <inputParameter name="PartnerId" displayName="Partner Id" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNos" displayName="Order Nos" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNumber" displayName="Order Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PONumber" displayName="PO Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivationStartDate" displayName="Activation Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivationEndDate" displayName="Activation End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductDescr" displayName="Product Description" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivateeCompany" displayName="Activatee Company" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivateeEmail" displayName="Activatee Email" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderDirection" displayName="Order Direction" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3306" displayName="Reseller Partner Activation Asset Query Count">
                    <inputParameter name="PartnerId" displayName="Partner Id" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNos" displayName="Order Nos" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNumber" displayName="Order Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PONumber" displayName="PO Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivationStartDate" displayName="Activation Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivationEndDate" displayName="Activation End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductDescr" displayName="Product Description" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivateeCompany" displayName="Activatee Company" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ActivateeEmail" displayName="Activatee Email" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderDirection" displayName="Order Direction" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3309" displayName="Split Entitlement Product Key Report">
                    <inputParameter name="ProductKey" displayName="Product Key" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3310" displayName="Channel Partner User by EmailId Report">
                    <inputParameter name="EmailId" displayName="Email Id" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3299" displayName="Distributor Partner EON Asset Report">
                    <inputParameter name="PartnerId" displayName="Partner Id" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNos" displayName="Order Nos" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNumber" displayName="Order Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PONumber" displayName="PO Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderStartDate" displayName="Order Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderEndDate" displayName="Order End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductDescr" displayName="Product Description" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="AssociatePartyPartner" displayName="Associate Party Partner" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="AssociatedPartyEndUser" displayName="Associated Party EndUser" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="FilterOutActivatedAssets" displayName="Filter Out ActivatedAssets" type="BOOLEAN"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderByColumn" displayName="Order By Column" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderDirection" displayName="Order Direction" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3300" displayName="Distributor Partner EON Asset Query Count">
                    <inputParameter name="PartnerId" displayName="Partner Id" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNos" displayName="Order Nos" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNumber" displayName="Order Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PONumber" displayName="PO Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderStartDate" displayName="Order Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderEndDate" displayName="Order End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductDescr" displayName="Product Description" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="AssociatePartyPartner" displayName="Associate Party Partner" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="AssociatedPartyEndUser" displayName="Associated Party EndUser" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="FilterOutActivatedAssets" displayName="Filter Out ActivatedAssets" type="BOOLEAN"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderByColumn" displayName="Order By Column" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderDirection" displayName="Order Direction" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3303" displayName="Reseller Partner EON Asset Query Count">
                    <inputParameter name="PartnerId" displayName="Partner Id" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNos" displayName="Order Nos" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNumber" displayName="Order Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PONumber" displayName="PO Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderStartDate" displayName="Order Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderEndDate" displayName="Order End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductDescr" displayName="Product Description" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="AssociatedPartyEndUser" displayName="Associated Party EndUser" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="FilterOutActivatedAssets" displayName="Filter Out Activated Assets" type="BOOLEAN"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderByColumn" displayName="Order By Column" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderDirection" displayName="Order Direction" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3304" displayName="Reseller Partner EON Asset - Landing Page">
                    <inputParameter name="PartnerId" displayName="Partner Id" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNos" displayName="Order Nos" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNumber" displayName="Order Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PONumber" displayName="PO Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderStartDate" displayName="Order Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderEndDate" displayName="Order End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductDescr" displayName="Product Description" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="AssociatedPartyEndUser" displayName="Associated Party EndUser" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="FilterOutActivatedAssets" displayName="Filter Out Activated Assets" type="BOOLEAN"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderByColumn" displayName="Order By Column" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderDirection" displayName="Order Direction" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3301" displayName="Distributor Partner EON Asset - Landing Page">
                    <inputParameter name="PartnerId" displayName="Partner Id" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNos" displayName="Order Nos" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNumber" displayName="Order Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PONumber" displayName="PO Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderStartDate" displayName="Order Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderEndDate" displayName="Order End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductDescr" displayName="Product Description" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="AssociatePartyPartner" displayName="Associate Party Partner" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="AssociatedPartyEndUser" displayName="Associated Party EndUser" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="FilterOutActivatedAssets" displayName="Filter Out ActivatedAssets" type="BOOLEAN"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderByColumn" displayName="Order By Column" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderDirection" displayName="Order Direction" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3302" displayName="Reseller Partner EON Asset Report">
                    <inputParameter name="PartnerId" displayName="Partner Id" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNos" displayName="Order Nos" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNumber" displayName="Order Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PONumber" displayName="PO Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="EON" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductNumber" displayName="Product Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderStartDate" displayName="Order Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderEndDate" displayName="Order End Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="ProductDescr" displayName="Product Description" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="AssociatedPartyEndUser" displayName="Associated Party EndUser" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="FilterOutActivatedAssets" displayName="Filter Out Activated Assets" type="BOOLEAN"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderByColumn" displayName="Order By Column" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderDirection" displayName="Order Direction" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
            </reportGroup>
            <reportGroup name="Aruba Central Reports">
                <report id="3312" displayName="Aruba Central Subscription Key Report">
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="Subscription Key" type="STRING"/>
                </report>
                <report id="3313" displayName="Aruba Central Support Report">
                    <inputParameter name="StartDate" displayName="Start Date" type="DATE"/>
                    <inputParameter name="NumberofDays" displayName="Number of Days(1-31)" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="Region" displayName="Region" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="BackOffice" displayName="Back Office" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="Country" displayName="Country" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="OrderNumber" displayName="Order Number" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="EON" displayName="Subscription Key" type="STRING"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageNo" displayName="Page Number" type="NUMERIC"/>
                    <inputParameter name="PageSize" displayName="Page Size" type="NUMERIC"/>
                </report>
            </reportGroup>
        </reports>
    ]]>
</ReportContent>
```

Comment: You need to choose xpath extractor, if it is tough to extract content using the regular expression extractor. In your case, you can use regular expression extractor with this expression. <report id="([0-9]{4})" displayName="(.+?)"

Comment: You can extend the right boundary to retrieve the exact tag.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to get the xpath of the report tag having attribute displayName="Support Report" under the CDATA

It's inside CDATA. It isn't a tag and doesn't have an attribute. It is just text.

If you want to reach it with XPath then you need to:

1. Parse the XML
2. Extract the text content of the ReportContent element
3. Parse that text content as a new XML document
4. Write XPath to find the element in that new XML document